# Stuck in excel formula calling data from another sheet without changing cell reference

Tags: excel

My case is little different I am working on an excel sheet so far It was a success but now I am totally clue less, what I am trying to do is I have two sheets 
sheet1
sheet2

In sheet1 I am calling data from sheet2 suppose

in sheet1 a5 I am calling data from sheet2 c3 by this formula

```
=sheet2!c3
```

What I want to do is when I put a blank new row or column in sheet2 it automatically change the formula accordingly And I don't want it to do so, like it change it from

```
=sheet2!c3 into =sheet2!c4
```

I also tried putting $

```
=sheet2!$c$3
```

But it seems it only works on the same sheet not if you are calling data from another sheet, is there any way I can make this formula constant not change but remaining =Sheet2!c3 ??

Comment: The reason Excel behaves this way is for the day you actually want to add a blank row to your Excel sheet or re-position the displaying of your data. Why don't you insert the blank row underneath your formula? Things usually grow down and right.

Comment: I agree, without understanding the use case - this is a very odd thing to want to do.  There's a good reason why Excel does this if you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

That's how Excel works when you insert rows I am afraid.  You could try building the formula as a string value:

=INDIRECT("sheet2!C3",TRUE)

Comment: Disclaimer for large workbooks: Volatile Function, fasten your seat belt and prepare for impact.

Comment: It does, but I wonder how he would do it if he had 50k-100k rows from all that appending.

Comment: that would be a separate question then...!

Answer (score 0):

I just used the index function

```
=index(sheet2!c3,c,3)
```

and it works !

The above method is also 100%percent working and accurate.